# Change the value of a model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, heroku, attributes, twilio

I'm using Twilio to send SMS message to change the value of a particular model's (Users) attribute (in this case :money).

I'm successfully pulling params from the Twilio POST, though not having luck saving the attribute change to the model's attribute. Any thoughts?

Here's my code from 'update' in the Users controller:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }

      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'twilio-ruby'

    @account_sid = 'AC0626c6d8dc0a4551b159161c5ca7ced2'
    @auth_token = '**********************************'

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)

    message_body = params["Body"]
    from_number = params["From"]

    if from_number == "+**********"
      @user = User.find(1) # :select => :money
      existing_money = @user.money
      doug_sum = message_body.to_f + existing_money

      @user.money = doug_sum
      @user.save

      puts "This is Doug's sum: #{doug_sum} and it has been saved"
    else
      puts "This is not a valid frump number"  
    end

  end
```

Here's what the Heroku server logs say:

```
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 184.73.31.10 at 2012-06-27 21:09:06 +0000
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"AccountSid"=>"AC0626c6d8dc0a4551b159161c5ca7ced2", "Body"=>"4", "ToZip"=>"13203", "FromState"=>"NY", "ToCity"=>"SYRACUSE", "SmsSid"=>"SMa973490ac1db98b25247b600fe068d6f", "ToState"=>"NY", "To"=>"+13158491369", "ToCountry"=>"US", "FromCountry"=>"US", "SmsMessageSid"=>"SMa973490ac1db98b25247b600fe068d6f", "ApiVersion"=>"2010-04-01", "FromCity"=>"SYRACUSE", "SmsStatus"=>"received", "From"=>"+13154368655", "FromZip"=>"13135"}
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (5.4ms)
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (34.9ms)
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 36.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
2012-06-27T21:09:06+00:00 heroku[router]: POST frump.herokuapp.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=57ms status=200 bytes=1582
```

Lastly, here's the Twiml file receiving the SMS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Response>
    <Redirect method="POST">http://frump.herokuapp.com/users</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Here's the view code:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td>$<%= user.money %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your view code. As I can see in Heroku server log your parameter looks like `Parameters: {"AccountSid"=>"AC0626c6d8dc0a4551b159161c5ca7ced2", "Body"=>"4", "ToZip"=>"13203", "FromState"=>"NY", "ToCity"=>"SYRACUSE", "SmsSid"=>"SMa973490ac1db98b25247b600fe068d6f", "ToState"=>"NY", "To"=>"+13158491369", "ToCountry"=>"US", "FromCountry"=>"US", "SmsMessageSid"=>"SMa973490ac1db98b25247b600fe068d6f", "ApiVersion"=>"2010-04-01", "FromCity"=>"SYRACUSE", "SmsStatus"=>"received", "From"=>"+13154368655", "FromZip"=>"13135"}` but it should look like `Parameters: {"user" => {"AccountSid" => ..}}`

Comment: Posted the view code -- appreciate your help:

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest stepping through your logic incrementally and checking your assumptions in each case. Do you actually retrieve a User object?  Do you have a 'From' number or not? Does user.save update the value stored in the database? These are all places where the code could be breaking and it would be good to check each one.

Answer (score 1):

log says `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`, so probably you are not getting the data back from 'twilio' due to authentication failure from your rails app  side. Like having

```
protect_from_forgery
```

in you application controller.

Try to except your action from the forgery protection and see, something like

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => ["create"]
end
```

HTH